# How to prove $\{a_{n+k}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is convergent and that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_{n+k}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, elementary-number-theory, epsilon-delta

Let $\{a_{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ be a sequence of real numbers and let $k$ be a fixed natural number. If $\{a_{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is convergent, how to prove $\{a_{n+k}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is convergent and that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_{n+k}$.

In my opinion, if $\{a_{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is convergent, then $\forall\epsilon\gt 0, \exists N\in \Bbb{Z}^+$ such that if $N\le n$, then $|a_n-L|\lt \epsilon$. I think we can assume the condition to be true and say $\forall\epsilon_1\gt 0, \exists N_1\in \Bbb{Z}^+$ such that if $N_1-k\le n$ (since $k$ is natural number), then $N_1\le n+k$, then $|a_{n+k}-L_1|\lt \epsilon_1$. But I don't see it as a complete proof. Could someone give a clear one?

Comment: I think you're pretty close. How about we take our original $N\leq n$ and add $k$ to each side?

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is almost complete, if not totally right. However, you can formalize it a bit, as such :
If $\{a_{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is convergent, then $\forall\epsilon\gt 0, \exists N\in \Bbb{Z}^+$ such that if $N\le n$ then $|a_n-L|\lt \epsilon$. Therefore, the following condition also holds when $N+k\le n+k$. So, for $N_1 = N+k$, we have that if $N_1 \le n+k$, then $|a_{n+k}-L|\lt \epsilon$, for the same $\epsilon$ as before. And therefore, $a_{n+k}$ converges to the same limit as $a_{n}$.

More generally, a similar argument can be made for $a_{f(n)}$ where $f(n)$ is a function of $\Bbb{N} \rightarrow \Bbb{N}$ which is stricly increasing. Just apply the function to the inequality. Hence, every subsequence converges to the same point as the sequence itself, if it is convergent.

Comment: If the problem does not give the data that is the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$  converges, how do we think about this? we have to show $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is convergent. The given data is only $\lim_{n\xrightarrow[]{}\infty} (a_{n+k}- a_n)=0$

Comment: If the given data is only that, then it is not sufficent to show that the sequence converges. Consider $a_n = \sqrt{n}$, then $\lim_{n\xrightarrow[]{}\infty} (a_{n+k}- a_n)=0$ for all k>0, but the sequence is not convergent.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Let $k$ be fixed and suppose $a_n \to L$. Consider the sequence $(a_{k+n})_n$. Notice that the convergence of $a_n$ implies that there exists a $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have $|a_n-L|< \epsilon$. Observe then that if $n>N$ then $k+n>N$ and so $|a_{n+k}-L|<\epsilon$ and so we are done. This shows convergence and that they have the same limit $L$.

Comment: If the problem does not give the data that is the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$  converges, how do we think about this? we have to show $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is convergent. The given data is only $\lim_{n\xrightarrow[]{}\infty} (a_{n+k}- a_n)=0$